# Rspec eq() rounding numbers

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do you stop Rspec from rounding fixNum's in compares like eq()?

Ruby:

```
def power(base, exponent)
  base**exponent
end
```

Rspec:

```
Failure/Error: expect(power(5,-5)).to eq(1/3125)

   expected: 0
        got: (1/3125)
```

but passes with

```
expect(power(5,-5)).to eq(0.00032)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not RSpec rounding anything, it's simply Ruby assuming that since you're dividing two `Fixnum` then you want a `Fixnum` back.

If any of the numbers you were diving was a `Float` or `Rational` your division would yield the corresponding class and it will pass your equality check.

```
> power(5, -5) == (1/3125)
=> false
> power(5, -5).class
=> Rational
> (1/3125).class
=> Fixnum
> 0.00032.class
=> Float
> (1/3125)
=> 0
> (1.0/3125)
=> 0.00032
> power(5, -5) == (1.0/3125)
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks. When the original test failed with eq(0.00032) but returned 1/3125 I knew they were mathematically identical so I just copied the output to the eq() test.